# Powershell command to delete 2000+ same day calendar entries in Office 365?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, office365, outlook-2013

The title says it all.  One of our executives has 2000+﻿ series of the same exact meeting happening every single monday.  How that even happens? I have no idea.

I've tried running the following:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited | Search-Mailbox -TargetMailbox: "Email of User" -SearchQuery subject:"Subject of Calendar Entry" TargetFolder "Calendar" -DeleteContent
```

But I keep getting the following error:﻿

> A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
>   'Calendar'.
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Search-Mailbox], Parameter    BindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Search-Mailbox Invoke-Command : Cannot
>   write input as there are no more running pipelines At
>   C:\Users\administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_043dc405-8409-4b6a-aa5b-a8eaa5b24cba
>   _gjq20aee.wv2\tmp_043dc405-8409-4b6a-aa5b-a8eaa5b24cba_gjq20aee.wv2.psm1:39681
>   char:29
>   +             $scriptCmd = { & <<<<  $script:InvokeCommand `
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Command], PSInvali    dOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMoreInputWrite,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.I
>   nvokeCommandCommand

Comment: Does `TargetFolder` need to be `-TargetFolder`?

Answer (score 1):

You're piping the Get-Mailbox into the Search-Mailbox which means all mailboxes in the organization are going to be searched, instead of just your executive's.

The -TargetMailbox and -TargetFolder (which does indeed need a dash) are used to send search results to a folder within a mailbox, not specify the mailbox being searched.

Try this instead:

```
Search-Mailbox -Identity "Executive Name" -SearchQuery 'Subject:"Subject of calendar entry"' -DeleteContent
```

If you just want to find out how many items there are (max 10,000) and send the results to a mailbox you can do this:

```
Search-Mailbox -Identity "Executive Name" -SearchQuery 'Subject:"Subject of calendar entry"' -TargetMailbox "some.mailbox" -TargetFolder "Some Folder" -LogOnly -LogLevel Full
```

More info https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298173(v=exchg.150).aspx